Proper YAML configuration for ssh_security ansible role
I am creating an ansible rolke for configure ssh security on servers, following the documentation. Here is my YAML configuration file:
---
- name: Enable SSH security
  hosts: webservers
  tasks:
      - name: Ensure SSH is installed
        apt:
          name: openssh-server
          state: present

      - name: Configure SSH to disable password authentication
        lineinfile:
          path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
          regexp: '^#?PasswordAuthentication'
          line: 'PasswordAuthentication no'
        notify: Restart SSH

      - name: Ensure public key authentication is enabled
        lineinfile:
          path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
          regexp: '^#?PubkeyAuthentication'
          line: 'PubkeyAuthentication yes'
        notify: Restart SSH

      - name: Disable root SSH access
        lineinfile:
          path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
          regexp: '^#?PermitRootLogin'
          line: 'PermitRootLogin no'
        notify: Restart SSH

  handlers:
      - name: Restart SSH
        service:
          name: ssh
          state: restarted

It seem correct and well formatted, however when I run the playbook, I get this error:
SSH password: 
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: 
ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, tasks

The error appears to be in '/<full path>/Hetzner/roles/ssh_security/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Enable SSH security
  ^ here

The Pycharm IDE yaml parser does not accuse this error. What could be wrong in this configuration?

you are mixing up playbook and role syntax. You use the playbook structure inside roles tasks.
Use this a main playbook:
---
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - ssh_security

and /<full path>/Hetzner/roles/ssh_security/tasks/main.yml like so:
- name: Ensure SSH is installed
  apt:
    name: openssh-server
    state: present
[...]


put handler under /<full path>/Hetzner/roles/ssh_security/handlers/main.yml

Thanks a lot @henrik! but I am still getting an error in my handler code: ERROR! The handlers/main.yml file for role 'ssh_security' must contain a list of tasks. {'handlers': [{'name': 'Restart SSH', 'service': {'name': 'ssh', 'state': 'restarted'}}]} should be a list or None but is <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'>

Found the mistake. everything is working now!
